# Regarding OFDM (Orthogonal Frequency Division multiplexing)

Tags: multiplexer

Could you please briefly explain the IEEE 802.11a [OFDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing) packet structure? In particular,

1. What is meant by "symbol" here?
2. What is the purpose of the packet preamble?
3. What is a "short training symbol" and what is its purpose?
4. What is a "long training symbol" and what is its purpose?
5. What is a "signal field" and what is its purpose?

Why are we using 52 sub carriers in a weird way? I have searched a lot but nowhere could I find some basics. Could you please explain it properly?

Comment: The StackExchange model is generally one question per post, you have 5 here. The latter 4 also seem too broad to be answered in the StackExchange format, even individually.

Comment: I am sorry I am new here I didnt know, thing is I am trying to do thesis, its kinda not directly related to my field but I find it interesting and to undertand IEE802.11a I have to understand them altogether.........

Comment: This question should probably be asked on [dsp.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question probably would be better suited to StackExchange Digital Signal Processing, rather than StackExchange Physics.

Comment: @user44501 I answered your question thinking that you might be looking for something deeper and more physics related issue since this is not related to your thesis (which I'm assuming is in physics).

Answer (score 3):

Preambles are known patterns that allow for easy synchronization.  Preambles are used in signal processing as markers to help synchronize the hardware and software to the incoming data stream which is often too random to find patterns in.  Here's an 802.11 wlan frame.

[image: packet]

In real time:
[image: real time]

The 10 repetitions of the short preamble give the receiver hardware time to adjust.  During this time signal detection, AGC converges, timing acquisition and frequency acquisition is done.

The two long preambles (with a guard interval before it) are used for channel estimation and finer frequency adjustments before the data can be processed.

The third region of the frame is the Signal field, which consists of one OFDM symbol assigned to all 52 subcarriers. This symbol is BPSK modulated at 6 Mbps and is encoded at a ½ rate. The signal field is used to indicate the rate at which the OFDM symbols of the PSDU payload are transmitted and is not scrambled.

OFDM uses multiple carriers to spread the data out across the frequency band.  This helps reduce problems with signal fading, multi-path and narrow band interference.

Further introductory information can be found [here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/EE225C/Lectures/Lec16_ofdm.pdf).